# filter two objects in array angular 4, id and date

Tags: angular, filter

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cq43dr?file=app/components/transactionList/transactionList.ts)

Line 53

How can I add new if statement that will filter out date created and order id from my search input text.

I just wanna put some code on my method, I don't mind the table format. I just want to make the function work on my search input.

**private getTransactionNanmes()**

I can display the order ID already, when searching. I want two fields the ***order ID*** and **date created** when searching.

I have already installed momentJS in my stackblitz

```
 //return this.transactions.map((v) => moment(v.dateCreated).format("MMM Do YY"))
```

I already search lots of articles, and I'm new to es6 and angular 4
maybe this [one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003804/how-to-filter-array-of-object-by-multiples-array-objects-values?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: The problem is that your date is a number, not a string, so you must add a new property to your users (called e.g. dateCreatedTxt) with the date in string. use map to add this property. then you can search normally

Comment: How can I do that. I have already installed momentJS in my stackblitz 
     //return this.transactions.map((v) => moment(v.dateCreated).format("MMM Do YY"))