# Filter data with array- vuejs 2

Tags: vuejs2

I have an array object, and i want to filter that array. I already know how to filter data by single value using computed property,

```
computed: {
    filteredValue() {
        return this.graphData.filter(data => data.YEAR === this.selectedYears)
    }
},
```

But i want to filter data by multiple value/array. Suppose i have an array object that has Year: 1901-2000. and i only want to filter only those year which are selected (like 1901, 1902, 1903). Can anyone help me with that.
TIA

Comment: check this: [filtered with multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18719383/how-to-filter-an-array-object-by-checking-multiple-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to maintain an array of selectedYears.Then,use use it like this.

```
computed: {
   filteredValue() {
      return this.graphData.filter(data => this.selectedYears.includes(data.YEAR);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,, i also just figured it out.