# Filter objects using filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, ecmascript-6

I have array of object like below:

```
pages= [
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"name1",
      "languages":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "lang":"en"
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "lang":"de"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "name":"name2",
      "languages":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "lang":"en"
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "lang":"de"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "name":"name3",
      "languages":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "lang":"en"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

And array of languages(these will be set by clicking on checkboxes) is as below:

```
selectedLanguages=['en'];
```

Now, I want to filter the main array depending upon the `selectedLanguages` values. I have tried with below code:

```
pages.filter(page => {
    var present = false;
    page.languages.map(l => {
        if(selectedLanguages.includes(l.lang)) {
            present = true;
        }
    });
    if(present) {
        return page;
    }
})
```

Desired output: if `selectedLanguages = ['en']` then all items from `pages`, if `de` then first 2 elements.

It works but I am curious if I can make it better?

Any suggestions would be helpful :) Thanks.

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: I think this is what you are loking for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51023010/7848529)

Comment: Your example already works for me... Just assign the output of `pages.filter(...)` to another variable

Comment: I have mentioned that it works :) I wanted it to be better or compact solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`Array#Filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) for that :

```js
let pages= [
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"name1",
      "languages":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "lang":"en"
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "lang":"de"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "name":"name2",
      "languages":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "lang":"en"
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "lang":"fr"
         }
      ]
   }
]

let selectedLanguages=['fr'];

let result = pages.filter(e => e.languages.find(l => selectedLanguages.includes(l.lang)));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to create an intermediate array with `.map`, it would be better to simply check if `some` of the `languages` include a `lang` matching the `selectedLanguages`:

```js
const pages=[{"id":1,"name":"name1","languages":[{"id":1,"lang":"en"},{"id":2,"lang":"de"}]},{"id":2,"name":"name2","languages":[{"id":1,"lang":"en"},{"id":2,"lang":"de"}]}]
const selectedLanguages=['en'];
console.log(
  pages.filter(({ languages }) => (
    languages.some(({ lang }) => selectedLanguages.includes(lang))
  ))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()` with `indexOf()` check for the `selectedLanguages` array:

```js
var pages= [
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"name1",
      "languages":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "lang":"en"
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "lang":"de"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "name":"name2",
      "languages":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "lang":"en"
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "lang":"de"
         }
      ]
   },
    {
      "id":3,
      "name":"name3",
      "languages":[
         {
            "id":5,
            "lang":"us"
         },
         {
            "id":6,
            "lang":"de"
         }
      ]
   }
];

var selectedLanguages=['en'];

var res = pages.filter((page) => {
   var languageFound = page.languages.find(language => selectedLanguages.indexOf(language.lang) !== -1);
   if(languageFound){
     return page;
   }
});

console.log(res);
```